Import notebook within other notebook
I have a notebook in BQ studio (eg "Utils") with some functions, classes etc that I'd like to refer in another notebook (eg "MyNotebook"). I've tried importnb and other similar packages but I get a No module named 'Utils' error. I also tried the %run "Utils.ipynb" command but I get a File 'Utils.ipynb.py' not found error. Can you help?

Hi, can you add that screen shot of the error in the question , it gives more clarity .
